# Typescript in Sublime Text 3

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3

I am using typescript in Sublime Text 3 , and only when I save and press **Ctrl + B** , a JavaScript file gets created.

What I am looking for is, as soon as I save .ts file, .js file should be created.Any idea how to do that?

This question is specific to typescript.

Comment: Well, I don't think sublime is up for that.. You can actually do `tsc -w fileName` to keep watching it if it changes and compiles it to `.js`.

Comment: @choz yes, Sublime can do that.

Comment: @MattDMo Oh.. Nice to know it can run shell script when saving file.. yes.. Now I know its possible..